# Trying to create new workbooks based off data

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create new workbooks based off of data. works for one set of data but wont work for more. I have tested for 22- and 11- separately and it works but wont work together.  llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll

```
Dim rw As Long, lastrow As Long, MySel As Range 'Grabs skus and moves to new sheet

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For rw = 1000 To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(rw, 8).Value Like "*22-*" Then
            If MySel Is Nothing Then
                Set MySel = .Cells(rw, 1).EntireRow

                    Else
                        Set MySel = Union(MySel, .Cells(rw, 1).EntireRow)



                    Dim sWorkbook As Workbook

                     'Create New Workbook
                    Set sWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

                     'Save Above Created New Workbook
                     sWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\22 Production.xlsx"


                    End If
                End If
            Next rw
        End With

With Workbooks("22 Production").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Not MySel Is Nothing Then
        MySel.Copy Destination:=.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1)
        'MySel.Delete
    End If
End With

Dim rw1 As Long, lastrow1 As Long, mysel1 As Range 'Grabs skus and moves to new sheet

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For rw1 = 1000 To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(rw1, 8).Value Like "*11-*" Then
            If mysel1 Is Nothing Then
                Set mysel1 = .Cells(rw1, 1).EntireRow

                    Else
                        Set mysel1 = Union(mysel1, .Cells(rw1, 1).EntireRow)



                    Dim sWorkbook1 As Workbook

                     'Create New Workbook
                    Set sWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Add

                     'Save Above Created New Workbook
                     sWorkbook1.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CODE\11 Production.xlsx"


                    End If
                End If
            Next rw1
        End With

With Workbooks("11 Production").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Not mysel1 Is Nothing Then
        mysel1.Copy Destination:=.Cells(lastrow1 + 1, 1)
        'mysel1.Delete
    End If
End With
```

Subscript out of range

Comment: **but wont work together**: doesn't give us much to go on. What actually happens? Do you get and error? It runs through but nothing happens? please provide more details. Also, how did you try to make it run together? please provide the actual `IF` statement maybe

Comment: The error i get is "Subscript out of range" as stated at the bottom. As per more details; Im quite new to VBA and am not sure whats going wrong... I have a 22- and an 11- in the 8th row but i still get this error when both functions are in my code

Comment: Which line is giving you the `Subscript out of range` error? My guess is you're referencing a workbook or worksheet with a (slightly?) misspelled name or something like that.

Comment: You are creating the same workbook 999 times!?!

Comment: Change `With Workbooks("22 Production").Worksheets("Sheet1")` this to `With Workbooks("22 Production.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: And `With Workbooks("11 Production").Worksheets("Sheet1")` to `With Workbooks("11 Production.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: No I still get subscript out of range. i think the issue has to do with the way it searches for 22- because it only works when there is a 22- on row 2

Comment: You say `If MySe1 is Nothing` but prior to that you don't have it set to anything. Can we see which step is causing the error?

Comment: Im just going to send the data to a new sheet and then create te new workbook... Thanks for the help tho ! :)